# Parse this JSON OBJECT in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am going to be receiving a JSON object via HTTP POST and I am finding it difficult to parse it. This is what the JSON object looks like:

```
{ login: {username: 123, password: 456} }, questions:[{ name: "insomnia", type: "boolean", problem: true, question: "Did you experience    insomnia?", answer: null},{ name: "go-to-bed", type: "amount", problem: false, question: "When did you go to bed?", answer: null }]}
```

I want to parse it into 3 different variables $username, $password and $q

From the example, this is what I expect it to be:

`echo $username // **output:** 123`

`echo $password // **output:** 456`

`echo $q //**output:** questions:[{ name: "insomnia", type: "boolean", problem: true, question: "Did you experience    insomnia?", answer: null},{ name: "go-to-bed", type: "amount", problem: false, question: "When did you go to bed?", answer: null }]`

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)?

Comment: @JonStirling Tried that, but the problem is parsing the object that is stored in $q and storing it as a string. I don't know how to store the sub-JSON Object as a string without altering the integrity of the input. I am quite new to PHP. This might be really easy

Comment: Re-encode it? `$q = json_encode($decoded['questions']);`

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: _small note:_ That is not a valid JSONString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your example is not a valid json. Here the valid one:

```
[{
"login": {
    "username": 123,
    "password": 456
},
"questions": [{
    "name": "insomnia",
    "type": "boolean",
    "problem": true,
    "question": "Did you experience    insomnia?",
    "answer": null
}, {
    "name": "go-to-bed",
    "type": "amount",
    "problem": false,
    "question": "When did you go to bed?",
    "answer": null
}]
}]
```

Next you can use `json_decode` from a string:

```
$x = '[{
"login": {
    "username": 123,
    "password": 456
},
"questions": [{
    "name": "insomnia",
    "type": "boolean",
    "problem": true,
    "question": "Did you experience    insomnia?",
    "answer": null
}, {
    "name": "go-to-bed",
    "type": "amount",
    "problem": false,
    "question": "When did you go to bed?",
    "answer": null
}]
}]';

$q = json_decode($x);
print_r($q);
echo $q[0]->login->username;
```

Comment: The echo statement doesn't print anything

Comment: @GabrielAluyor sorry, I forget to put quotes. I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

The JSON in the example is invalid, I fixed it and put together a test, I think this is what you're looking for.

```
<?php
$json = <<<JSON
{
  "login": {
    "username": 123,
    "password": 456
  },
  "questions": [
    {
      "name": "insomnia",
      "type": "boolean",
      "problem": true,
      "question": "Did you experience insomnia?",
      "answer": null
    },
    {
      "name": "go-to-bed",
      "type": "amount",
      "problem": false,
      "question": "When did you go to bed?",
      "answer": null
    }
  ]
}
JSON;

$decoded = json_decode($json);

$username = $decoded->login->username;
$password = $decoded->login->password;

// Re-encode questions to a JSON string
$q = json_encode($decoded->questions);

echo $username."\n";
echo $password."\n";
echo $q."\n";
```

Comment: This did it for me but I had to make some changes.  

echo $q[0][login][username];

echo $q[0][login][password];

echo json_encode($q[0][questions]);

But unfortunately, I can't upvote the answer--not enough reputation.

Comment: @GabrielAluyor I think you meant to reply to the other answer.